# rsyslog: using message properties in a template

Tags: rsyslog

I am running Docker with journald log driver, and I am using rsyslog (v8.29.0) to collect these messages and write them to a file annotated with information about the container.  The problem I have encountered is that I am not able to use message properties in the `$!` namespace in templates unless I first move them into e.g. the local `$.` namespace.

I started with this configuration:

```
module(load="imjournal" StateFile="imjournal.state")

template(name="ContainerTemplate" type="list") {
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339" caseConversion="lower")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="$!CONTAINER_NAME")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="$!CONTAINER_ID")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\n")
}

if (strlen($!CONTAINER_NAME) > 0) then {
    action(type="omfile"
        file="/var/log/containers.log"
        template="ContainerTemplate")
}
```

Even when `$!CONTAINER_NAME` and `$!CONTAINER_ID` are defined, they expand to empty strings in the resulting template.  I can work around it like this, by explicitly setting new properties using the value of the existing properties:

```
template(name="ContainerTemplate" type="list") {
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339" caseConversion="lower")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="$.container_name")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="$.container_id")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\n")
}

if (strlen($!CONTAINER_NAME) > 0) then {

    set $.container_name = $!CONTAINER_NAME;
    set $.container_id = $!CONTAINER_ID;

    action(type="omfile"
        file="/var/log/containers.log"
        template="ContainerTemplate")
}
```

This works fine...but, if I change the case of the local variables (i.e., if I use `$.CONTAINER_NAME` and `$.CONTAINER_ID` instead of the lower-case equivalents), it behaves the same as the original configuration (I get empty strings in the log even though I am explicitly setting the properties).

Do you know what's going on here?  According to the [the docs](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html), the `property` statement "can access all properties", so I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and fixed it by making the template case sensitive.

Alter the line

`template(name="ContainerTemplate" type="list") {`

into

`template(name="ContainerTemplate" type="list" option.casesensitive="on") {`